# Are Shepherd's Notes the same as a commentary?

Tags: bible-commentary

I overheard someone talk about [Shepherd's Notes](https://www.olivetree.com/store/product.php?productid=77410).  They described it as Cliff's Notes for books of the Bible and will help you understand things you read in the Bible.  However, to me it sounds like a commentary.  If anyone has used Shepherd's Notes before, is it the same as a commentary?  If it's the same as a commentary, why would someone use Shepherd's Notes?

I [found them on Amazon](https://www.amazon.com/s?k=shepherd%27s+notes&crid=N5I6J0TBKDTZ&sprefix=shepherd%27s+note%2Caps%2C160&ref=nb_sb_noss_2) but there wasn't any sample pages for me to skim.  Also my local libraries don't seem to have them either for me to look at either.

Comment: In case it's helpful, some representative photos of the inside of the book can be found on Ebay. Examples: https://www.ebay.com/itm/385362437552 ; https://www.ebay.com/itm/194077290830 – it seems to be a commentary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This **[Shepherd's Notes: John](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/146274964X)** on Amazon has does have sample pages (go to the page and click on the image of the cover that has "Look Inside" written just above it).

Be sure to look at the preview for the Paperback version, as it allows you to see more than the Kindle one. It doesn't give you too much to look at; it only goes through pages 14, and most of those pages are introductory material and of little help, but we do still have pages 11-14 to give you an indication of its style.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1809/50259). I would also recommend reading the [Help Center](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help)'s sections on asking and answering questions.